# Case sensitive variable within .bat file

Tags: variables, batch-file, cmd, case, case-sensitive

I have an extremely simple batch file with a very annoying problem.  I am trying to stop a process via its TASKKILL using it's image name (/IM). The problem is I have two image names that are the same only difference being one is capitalized and the other is not.  I only want the all lowercase process to be killed. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
FOR /f "tokens=2" %%i IN (
 ' tasklist ^| find "ccc.exe" '
 ) DO SET pid=%%i
IF DEFINED pid ECHO TASKKILL /pid %pid%
```

This batch should do as you ask. I just used `ccc` as a test - `ccc.exe` does not exist (gave no output) `CCC.exe` exists - showed PID for `CCC.exe` when changed to upper-case.

You'd need to change the `tokens=` to 3 or perhaps even more if the executable name contains spaces, commas, semicolons, etc. Need to know the precise name to give you precise details.

Will simply show the PID it proposes to kill. Remove the `ECHO` to activate after verifying.

```
tasklist /fi "imagename eq whatever"
```

should list the target PIDs for you.